# Total derivative limit by hand

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

[image]

Why should the limit on the last line imply that the 2D limit is zero? I interpret the last line as saying for fixed $k$, the limit holds.

Comment: Use the inequality $|(h,k)|\geq |h|$ so that $\frac{1}{|(h,k)|}\leq \frac{1}{|h|}$

Comment: Ah so you can reuse the same $\epsilon-\delta$ pairs basically